# How to fix this weird calculation in pascal?

Tags: pascal

My code is very simple:

```
read(m,n);
Str(m*n,s);
writeln(s);
```

and if i put 1000000000 for both m and n as a result i get -1486618624 , also m and n are longint, so they aren't over the limit with 1 000 000 000.

Comment: Min longint value = -2147483648
   Max longint value = 2147483647

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `m*n` is 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 and does not fit in a `LongInt`. Try using `Int64` or `QWord` instead.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve it when it's 10^100 000 . For example i have number n which is lower than 10^100 000 and m, and i should first n mod m ? I also tried doing it with string but it's way too complicating then, and time limit for this task is 0.1 seconds. Also before anyone says it it's not for school or cheating, i am learning pascal on my own, i don't even learn it at school.

Comment: Search for a "bigint" unit, there are several. Choices depend on calculating performance (favors binary) vs display (favours decimal)